When do binary operators denote permutations? - Groups, Monoids, Semigroups.
Edit. (Copied from a comment I posted below...) Cayley's Theorem tells us that for any group $G,$ there exists a subgroup in symmetry group $S_n$ for some $>0$ (may not be finite) which $G$ is group isomorphic to. Hence, Cayley's Theorem demonstrates how the group operator induces symmetry structure on each element of a group (i.e. each element of  corresponds a "symmetry" on the underlying set of group ). But what is a "symmetry"? The definition I'm going off of states that symmetry is any bijection $→$ (i.e. permutation).

The underlying motive in asking this questions stems from (very elementary) Group Theory. In particular, an observation I made is that "group operators" define symmetry on the underlying set of the group. (This is immediately clear from Cayley's Theorem...see remark from start of post) With this observation, I became curious to see how far we could weaken the conditions inherent to a "group operator" so as to retain this symmetry behavior. This immediately led to the examination of binary operators on semigroups and monoids. However, in my study of these two far-less-strict examples of group operators which are binary operators, I found myself reaching a conclusion which I was unsure upon.
To explicitly restate my question: Is it possible that a groupoid operator (in the particular instance where identity property and inverse property do not hold true) may define a symmetry on the underlying set of a groupoid? Is it possible that a monoid operator (in the particular instance where inverse property does not hold true) may define a symmetry on the underlying set of a monoid?
The conclusion I have managed to reach is that no, this will never be possible. The reason being that in order for $\lambda_x:G\to G$ (defined s.t. $\lambda_x(g)=xg$) to be considered a symmetry on $G,$ it is necessary that for all $h\in G$ there exists a unique solution $x\in G$ to the equation $xg=h.$ When dealing with monoids, if this were to hold true for all $h,$ then this would imply the existence of $g=x^{-1}$ in the instance of $h=e$ (the identity). When dealing with groupoids...I'm a little stuck. However, the existence of a unique solution which satisfies the equation $xg=h$ reads a little bit as though there will exist an element $g\in G$ which is $=x^{-1}h$ in all but name.
I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

What do you mean by "symmetry" when you say "...'group operators' define symmetry on the underlying set..."? Namely, what "is immediately clear from Cayley's Theorem"?

@Kan't Cayley's Theorem tells us that for any group $G,$ there exists a subgroup in symmetry group $S_n$ for some $n>0$ (may not be finite) which $G$ is group isomorphic to. Hence, Cayley's Theorem demonstrates how the group operator induces symmetry structure on each element of a group (i.e. each element of $G$ corresponds a "symmetry" on the underlying set of group $G$). But what's symmetry? The definition I'm going off of states that symmetry is any bijection $G\to G$ (i.e. permutation). Does this answer your question?

Yes, and your clarification answers yours, I think: if the proof of Cayley's theorem uses all the axioms of a group, then the lack of any of them at least endenger its validity. So, I guess monoids and semigroups do not induce "symmetries" (bijections) of the underlying set.

The above comment from the OP can be edited/merged into the question.

@TymaGaidash Just added it.

Hello. I am confused on why this question is closed? (And why one of the individuals who voted to close the question chose to not only downvote my initial post, but also CyclotomicField's response?) I thought I was clear in my definition of symmetry?

@JAG131 Did not downvote, but there were 4/5 close votes before the last edit, so any user could close it, but it is being reopened/reviewed now.

@TymaGaidash I see. Thanks for letting me know. Any further clarity that's needed, please let me know.

Consider a collections of rotations generated by an irrational multiple of $2\pi$ about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ acting on the unit circle with the binary operation being composition. This will not contain an identity or inverses but they are all still isometries.

Does this "define a symmetry on the underlying set" in the way the OP meant? I'm not sure. In this example, I think OP is asking for symmetries on the collection of rotations, rather than the circle, and it doesn't seem like we have those, in the sense of "symmetry" that seems to be implied.

@ChrisCulter This response CyclotomicField has provided is very satisfactory. (+1) However, I do not believe it does address my question which relates the groupoid/monoid operators inducing a symmetry, unless I'm not seeing something? In particular, I'm looking for a binary operator which induces symmetry, hence collection of symmetries acting on itself. So if the rotations could be represented by points on the circle via well-defined permutation associated with each point, then this answer would directly address the specific type of "symmetry" I'm interested in...I think?

@ChrisCulter But in any case, I do believe proposition 1.4 from Hungerford (Let $G$ be a semigroup. Then $G$ is a group if and only if $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have solutions in $G.$) answers my question that in fact groupoid operators cannot induce symmetry on the underlying set associated with the groupoid unless it is a group operator.

The Cayley-theorem view of a group $G$ is that we may view its elements as bijections $\sigma: G\to G$, and hence $G$ embeds into the group $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Conversely, for a finite set $X$, any set $S$ of bijections $X\to X$ which form a semigroup are in fact a group, as repeated application of a single bijection will end up at the identity map, so we have an identity and elements have inverses.
This gives a negative answer for finite semigroups.
For infinite semigroups, the natural numbers can be made to act bijectively on the underlying set, and to see this simply note that there exists a group with an element of infinite order, and hence there exists a bijection of any infinite set, and hence of the set $\mathbb{N}$, which has infinite order. As it has infinite order, this bijection on $\mathbb{N}$ therefore acts like $\mathbb{N}$, so we have our counter-example.

On the other hand, consider functions $f:X\to X$ rather than bijections. The full transformation semigroup $\mathcal{T}(X)$ is the set of functions $X\to X$ under composition. Then, writing $S^1$ for the semigroup $S$ with an identity adjoined, we have:
Theorem.
If $S$ is a semigroup and $X=S^1$ then there is a monomorphism $\rho: S\to\mathcal{T}(S)$.
This means that $S$ acts on $S^1$, just not bijectively.
